# I tried to install Tkinter in python. But I cannot install it

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to install Tkinter in python 2.7.9
I tried sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-tk
i even tried to upgrade python so as to install Tkinter but that didn't work either.
Everytime i try to install this is what comes

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree  

Reading state information... Done

Package python-tk is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-tk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: My version is 15.04 is it because of the version

Answer (score 0):

You're running a version of Ubuntu that reached EOL in 2016, Ubuntu 15.04. Follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/423973) to upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu, or simply do a fresh install of the latest supported releases, 16.04 (LTS) or 17.10. Then try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-tk
```

Comment: already tried didn't work still thanks for helping

Comment: @user529674 I have edited my answer according to the new information that you have provided.